# "Наездник" и "жокей"

Tags: лексика, синонимы

"Наездник" и "жокей" — это синонимы или есть какая-то разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, это разные понятия. Жокей — это тот, кто ездит на лошади верхом и участвует в скачках, а наездник — тот, кто ездит в "качалке", двухколесной коляске, в которую запрягаются рысаки на бегах. Наездник верхом не ездит.

Answer (score 2):

Жокей — 1. **Профессиональный** **наездник** на скачках. 2. Специалист по тренингу и испытаниям верховых лошадей.
*текст курсивом*

Наездник — 1.устар. Тот, кто едет верхом; всадник; 2. Тот, кто владеет искусством *верховой* езды; специалист по вольтижировке.  Специалист по тренировке рысистых лошадей; участник рысистых бегов.
Так что в некотором смысле это синонимы. Наездник - более широкое понятие.

Comment: Это говорит словарь. А я пишу как человек хорошо разбирающийся в конном спорте.
Более широкое понятие - это "всадник", а наездник - тот, кто ездит в качалке на рысистых бегах.

Comment: Тогда, наверное, нужно упомянуть, что в профессиональной среде употребление данных слов имеет свои особенности :-) А в словаре зафиксировано общеязыковое значение.

Comment: Я бы не стал вообще профжаргон тут упоминать. Крутые каменщики кирпич тоже ложут - и никак иначе. Что нам теперь, словари раздувать?!

Тут вот какая штука. Различия между бегами и скачками давно перестали быть интересны всем, кто не является постоянным посетителем ипподромов. Соответственно и понимания различия в профессиях представителей этих двух спортивных направлений давно стерлись. 
Вне же спортивной сферы никому и в голову не придёт называть наездников не всадника (жокея), а, скажем, извозчика или возницу на подводе. А ведь сдедуя "строгой" терминологии следовало бы поступать именно так