# Всадник и наездник. Есть ли разница в смысле?

Tags: семантика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно: *всадник Буцефала* или *наездник Буцефала*?

Comment: см. также http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне все не очень нравится, если это не эпитет, конечно.
Для начала, ни "всадник кого", ни "наездник кого" - вообще не выглядит грамматически правильным. Всадник/наездник царя Гороха - это еще понятно, но конь-то причем? Тут совсем другое отношение принадлежности.

А по поводу самого слова, тут такое дело.
Всадник - тот кто едет на коне.
Наездник - тот, кто ездит, умеет ездить верхом. Историческое значение (наездник = всадник) устарело. Хотя и могло сохраниться в специальной терминологии, в конном спорте, например. 
Поэтому, если в современном тексте речь идет о едущем на Буцефале Македонском - то всадник.

Но не "всадник Буцефала", если это нейтральный стилистический образ, в нейтральном стиле пристегивать человека к коню как-кто совсем негоже. Для этого есть **"всадник на Буцефале"**. Ну еще "Буцефал под седлом такого-то".

А наездник - это "водитель кобылы", только верховой. В крайнем случае - "объездчик Буцефала".

Итак, **"всадник на Буцефале"** - в обычном тексте, и только в стихах, как эпитет - **"всадник Буцефала"**, да и то десять раз подумать. Но не наездник, "наездник" - это профессия.

Comment: В данном случае "всадник Буцефала" -- эпитет. В сети есть стихотворение В. Шендрика  "Всё так же алчен всадник Буцефала..." Спасибо, behemothus!

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что "наездник" - это "верховой водитель". Среди профессий лошадиных "водителей" есть ямщик, кучер, жокей, есть конные спортсмены, есть разного рода кавалеристы, но нет наездника. "Наездник" как профессия существует в рысистых бегах, но там как правило едут не верхом.

Comment: @enkryptor Вы слишком глубоко копаете. Все так, как вы говорите, но это тот уровень понимания, который нам нужен. Я всего лишь противопоставлял верхового (сидящему на лошади) тягловому (колясочнику, управляющему каретой, экипажем). И "водитель" у меня тоже обобщенно.

Answer (score 2):

В профессиональной среде "наездник" - человек, участвующий в бегах и управляющий рысаком, в то время как "всадник" - человек верхом на лошади.

В разговорной речи эти слова взаимозаменяемы, хотя [словари утверждают](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/870026), что слово "наездник" в смысле "всадник" звучит устаревше:

> 1. Человек, едущий верхом, всадник (устар.). *«Толпа наездников младых в дубраве едет молчаливой.» Пушкин.*